# Как правильно создать объект json для его отправки в post запрос?

Tags: android, json

Мне нужно создать объект json с данными о пользователе(email, first_name, last_name, password), чтобы отправить его post запросом.

```
String name = "[{\"email\":" + "\"" + email + "\"" + ",\"first_name\":" + "\"" + firstName + "\""
                        +  ",\"last_name\":" + "\"" + lastName + "\"" + ",\"password\":" + "\"" + newPassword + "\"" + "}]";


try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(name);
                Log.d("myLogs", obj.toString());

            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.e("myLogs", t);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте метод генератор:

```
 private static JsonObject jsonGenerator(JsonObject baseObj, String 
 parameterName, Boolean parameterValue) {
    baseObj.addProperty(parameterName, parameterValue);
    return baseObj;
}
```

Создаете jsonObject и передаете в body запроса:

```
  public static JsonObject createProfileData(String name, first_name, 
                                          String email) {
    JsonObject createdJson = new JsonObject();
    jsonGenerator(createdJson, "name", name);
    jsonGenerator(createdJson, "first_name", first_name);
    jsonGenerator(createdJson, "email", email);

    return createdJson;
}
```

пример запроса если используете Retrofit:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("healthbook/diary")
public Call<Profile> sendProfileData(@Body JsonObject dataToSend);
```

Comment: Workapp Workapp, а что такое jsonGenerator, он не определяется

Comment: пардон , обновил ответ.

Comment: Workapp Workapp, спасибо